Problem with getting signer using Wallet Connect
First time building mobile dapp and Im trying using Wallet Connect for dapp. But it seems like maybe I cant get sign of my wallet address (getSigner()). I always get this error
Error: no such account
This is my function that I tried to run
  const incrementValue = async () => {
    try {
      // const provider = await new ethers.JsonRpcProvider(sepolia.rpcUrl);
      const walletProvider = new ethers.JsonRpcProvider(sepolia.rpcUrl)
      const signer = await walletProvider.getSigner(); // Ensure the user is connected with their wallet
      if (!signer) {
        alert('Please connect your wallet first!');
        console.log('Please connect your wallet first!');
        return;
      }
      const contract = await new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, contractABI, signer);

      const tx = await contract.increment(); // Call the increment function
      await tx.wait(); // Wait for the transaction to be mined
      getValue(); // Refresh the value after increment
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error incrementing value:", error);
    }
  };


note that the sepolia.rpcUrl I used is https://rpc.sepolia.org
and
I'm not sure how to write proper code since im quite new to web3.
